# Site set up for SEO from creation

Tags: seo

I heard an SEO guy talk about a site he is seeing good results for, but that site was set up for SEO from its creation.

I presume this is not on page optimisation related since the context was sitewide and hard to replicate.   If you want to set up a site with SEO in mind from the go what is needed.

All I can think of is having 100s or more pages of content being SEO friendly Vs a site that has 20 pages that it needs.

What else could he be referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it means is that he kept SEO in mind from the beginning of the construction of the website (semantic markup, good usability, good accessibility, etc). (Really, if a site is built properly, it is SE friendly by default but that's a discussion for another time).

FYI, quantity of content does not equal quality of content. Quality of content is what affects SEO, not quantity.

Comment: thats what I was thinking.  I guess there was some sales speak involved.  thanks